# How do I print special characters like tabulations or newlines?

Tags: string, haskell

```
[m@green09 ~]$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> print "asdf"
"asdf"
Prelude> print "\tasdf"
"\tasdf"
Prelude>
```

Awesome. Just awesome.

How to print a tabulation or newline?

Comment: Use `putStrLn`, not `print`. `print = putStrLn . show`.

Comment: @AJFarmar This begs the question... [Can I use special characters like tabulations and newlines in Show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105976/can-i-use-special-characters-like-tabulations-and-newlines-in-show)

Comment: No it doesn’t. Yes you can. The only related this might *raise* is which characters `Show :: String -> String` will choose to escape

Comment: This behavior of `print` is so that one can correctly understand strings within larger types. E.g. if we print a `[String]` which contains the (unescaped) string `"aa", "bb"`, we really want to see that properly escaped so that we read e.g. `["first", "\"aa\", \"bb\"", "last"]` and _not_ the unescaped `[first, "aa", "bb", last]` which is ambiguous. This escaping is really useful when printing complex types, and a bit annoying when printing single strings -- but there's always `putStrLn` to write a string without escaping it.

Answer (score 1):

You just do it.

```
> putStrLn "a\tb"
a   b
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a value of type `Show a => a` into the REPL, the ghci will execute `print` on it, and if type of this value is `IO ()` it will just evaluate it. If you look at the definition of print you will see that `print = putStrLn . show`, or less pointfree: `print s = putStrLn (show s)`.

The problem is that `show` is not a tool for pretty printing. This function's purpose is to "show" the underlying structure, so that it can be `read` back by Haskell or by human. This is the point where the escaping characters are revealed. You may check that `show "\t" /= "\t"`.

If you want to actually print the string "as it is" you should explicitly call `putStr` or `putStrLn` action, that will omit this `show` layer.

---

Few examples:

```
>>> putStrLn "a\tb"
a    b

>>> "a\tb"
"a\tb"

>>> show "a\tb" -- notice that it is actually `putStrLn (show (show "a\tb"))`!
"\"a\\tb\""

>>> print "a\tb"
"a\tb"
```