# Can I use special characters like tabulations and newlines in Show?

Tags: string, haskell, printing

```
data Pair = P Int Int

instance Show Pair where
  show (P n1 n2) = (show n1) ++ "\t" ++ (show n2)
```

Result:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
\Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( labn.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> show (P 5 6)
"5\t6"
```

OK for a pair of ints this might be an artificial problem, but my actual use case is trying to pretty print a tree - where newlines and tabs seem instrumental for readability.

Can I somehow use these  characters with `show`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print special characters like tabulations or newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105774/how-do-i-print-special-characters-like-tabulations-or-newlines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`show` returns a string, and then when you put that in GHCi, it does `print . show $ (P 5 6)`, which is equivalent to `putStrLn . show . show $ (P 5 6)` which will print all the characters.

The problem is with the double show.

What you want to do is use print only, as `print (P 5 6)`. If you're using the GHCi, `print` is automatically applied to every expression, so you only need to type

```
Prelude> P 5 6
```